# Cannot receive field from PHP query

Tags: php, oracle

I have the following code :

```
 <?php  
//$adress = $_POST['forgotpass'];
$adress = 'test@example.com';
$test = 'test';
$conn = oci_connect( 'con', 'con', "localhost/xe");
$array = oci_parse($conn, "select password from t1 , t2 where id  = user_id and email = :adress");
oci_bind_by_name($array, ':adress', $adress);
oci_execute($array);

while($row=oci_fetch_array($array))

{

echo $row[0];

}
```

This code does not print anything, I suppose it is like this because of the symbols . or @ from my email adress.

The fact is that when I use a variable it works.

```
<?php  
//$adress = $_POST['forgotpass'];
$adress = 'test@example.com';
$test = 'test';
$conn = oci_connect( 'con', 'con', "localhost/xe");
$array = oci_parse($conn, "select password from t1 , t2 where id  = user_id and name = :test");
oci_bind_by_name($array, ':test', $test);
oci_execute($array);

while($row=oci_fetch_array($array))

{

echo $row[0];

}
```

And in this way it shows me on the screen what i do want to see. I don't see the problem with the email adress because I do the exact same thing. But , as I've said  I think that's because of those symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried single-quoting your :adress variable?

something like:

```
$array = oci_parse($conn, "select password from t1 , t2 where id  = user_id and email = ':adress'");
```

Comment: Yes , I've tried, and many more, still , the problem is from that dot , anyway, i managed to replace the dot with comma and then make an extra query to select the email how i'd like it to :D

Comment: Good to hear you'd found a workaround @lexraid , however may I advise you not to hard code your SQL in the front-end. I believe a better approach could be to create a stored procedure which implements your query, receives your filter strings as parameters, and then returns an open cursor with the results, that way you will be working with the native parsing capabilities of the DBMS and not the ones from the framework integration.

Comment: You're so right, thanks , I will remember your advice.